# Next.js 14.0.2 and 14.0.3 build error but ok with 14.0.1

Tags: next.js, next.js14

I have a multilingual project in development since 13.5 and upgrade to 14.0.1 and using App Router.
npm run dev and build both work correctly. deploy ok to vercel

but upgrade to 14.0.2 or 14.0.3, npm run build will fail with
Error occurred prerendering page "individual path to each files I got here". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')

so now development stuck in 14.0.1

has anyone come across this situation? the prerender error's possible reasons are:

**[Possible Ways to Fix It](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error)**

1. Use Next.js 13 (or higher) and the App Router, which allows
   colocation of pages and other files (e.g. components, styles, tests,
   etc)
2. Make sure to move any non-pages out of the pages folder
3. Check for any code that assumes a prop is available, even when it might not be
4. Set default values for all dynamic pages' props (avoid undefined, use null instead so it can be serialized)
5. Check for any out of date modules that you might be relying on
6. Make sure your component handles fallback if it is enabled in getStaticPaths. Fallback docs
7. Make sure you are not trying to export (output: 'export' or next export) pages    that have server-side rendering enabled
   getServerSideProps

I think I can ruled out reason #1, #2, #5, #6, #7
Then what would contribute to #2 or #3 that npm run build is fine with 14.0.1 but not 14.0.2 onward?

what's the changes since 14.0.2 that may break the build process??